# PowerShell Shortcut for deleting word to the left of the cursor

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, powershell

Spent the last 3 hours looking for a shortcut to delete the word to the left of the cursor in PowerShell ( Version 5.1.14409.1005 ) ........ without success.
I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for

> CTRL + Backspace

Backspace deletes to the left of the cursor

CTRL modifies to a word (CTRL Left/Right move the cursor one word left/right too)

This works for me on 5.1.17763.771 anyway - but those are fairly standard uses of CTRL and Backspace in CMD/powershell

I'm fairly certain that `CTRL` as a shortcut modifier from characters to words has been around since the 90's in DOS/CMD and is fairly common across at least the windows interface.

> CTRL + left/right/backspace/(probably others)

These work across CMD / Powershell  / notepad / Word / notepad++ / this WYSIWYG web widget / etc

Comment: PowerShell uses the PSReadLine Module for this, to see a list of available shortcuts  run `Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler`

Comment: Tried all those previous to the post with no success

Answer (score 0):

in powershell.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> - to erase a whole word, left of cursor